# How to Write into multiple files?

Tags: bugs, version-8, streams

Note: this is fixed in version 9.

---

I want to put expressions into multiple files simultaneously, with the following code:

```
tex1 = OpenWrite["test1.txt"];
tex2 = OpenWrite["test2.txt"];

Write[{tex1, tex2}, "anything"]

Close[tex1];
Close[tex2];
```

Why is `test2.txt` empty? Why does it work correctly with `WriteString` instead of `Write`? Now of course I can always `Map` the `Write` statements over streams, or just go with `WriteString`, but since it would be convenient to use a list as `Write`'s first argument I did post this issue. Is it a bug?

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing, what do you think of this?

Comment: It seems like a possible bug. I will report it.

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing István has indicated that this bug has been unfixed for at least 5 years: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/bd9b6dfd356fa886/dfe3e85496a3d2b4?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=Istv%C3%A1n+Zachar#dfe3e85496a3d2b4

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing: Thanks for reporting it. This raises another [meta question](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190/how-to-report-bugs) in me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug and fixed in the development version. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StreamsAndLowLevelInputAndOutput.html#11211), both `Write` and `WriteString` should accept an "output channel," which is just a list of streams.  On my system (v.8 on MacOS), `Write` behaves the same way as on your system when outputting anything, but `WriteString` behaves as expected.

Similarly, this

```
Write[{tex1, tex2}, 3, 4];
```

also misbehaves in the same manner.  So, the issue isn't limited to string output.